# How do I create a new database in MongoDB using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Can I create a new database simply by connecting to the MongoDB server, or is there another way to create it using Python? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**MongoDB** creates databases and collections automatically for you if they don't exist already.

For using python library with MongoDB, check out this **[documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1/tutorial.html)**.

> **Warning**:
>   the example is based on Pymongo **2.1**.
>   If you're using Pymongo **3.4**, check **[this doc](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)**.

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection()
db = connection['test-database']
collection = db['test-collection']
```

So here you can use any name for database and collection.

Comment: An important note: neither the database nor the collection are created until you attempt to write a document. That's adequate for most applications, but it's good to know.

Comment: I just read the Connection class is deprecated and you should use MongoClient instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959790/pymongo-mongoclient-or-connection

Comment: This answer is not up to date. See the one below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039275/6655465

Answer (score 33):

This is Mongodb 3.4 Version:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.primer
coll = db.dataset
```

> neither the database nor the collection are created until you attempt
>   to write a document.

Document: [Python Driver (PyMongo)](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/client/)

Comment: Thumbs up for specifying the Pymongo version :)! The way that Pymongo works from version 2.1 (example above) to 3.4, are totally different.

Answer (score 4):

For **pymongo==4.3.3**:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
print(client.list_database_names())
db = client["new_db"]
collection = db["new_collection"]
print( db.list_collection_names())
```

the database and collection are only going to be created when attempt to write a document.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to create a collection without inserting the documents in order to be able to set validators first.

Luckily the pymongo Database object defines [create_collection](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection) method:

> `create_collection(name, codec_options=None, read_preference=None, write_concern=None, read_concern=None, session=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Create a new Collection in this database.
>
> Normally collection creation is automatic. This method should only be used to specify options on creation. CollectionInvalid will be raised if the collection already exists.
>
> ...
>
> Changed in version 3.11: This method is now supported inside
> multi-document transactions with MongoDB 4.4+.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Added session parameter.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: Added the collation option.
>
> Changed in version 3.0: Added the codec_options, read_preference, and
> write_concern options.
>
> Changed in version 2.2: Removed deprecated argument: options