# pymongo: MongoClient or Connection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect mongodb using pymongo. I see two classes to connect to mongodb.

```
MongoClient and Connection.
```

What is the difference of these two classes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MongoClient` is the preferred method of connecting to a mongo instance. The `Connection` class is deprecated. But, in terms of use they are very similar.

Comment: i am trying to connect ssl connection with mongoDB using MongoClient it is connecting but why it's not connecting with Connection method

Answer (score 6):

MongoClient and Connection are similar but MongoClient was introduced *(since mongodb 2.2+ onwards)* to mainly support `WriteConcern` and other features.

`Connection` is depreciated, so avoid using it in future.

The first step when working with PyMongo is to create a `MongoClient` to the running mongod instance. Doing so is easy:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
```

The above code will connect on the default host and port. We can also specify the host and port explicitly, as follows:

```
>>> client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

Or use the MongoDB URI format:

```
>>> client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
```

Reference: [MongoClient Python Example](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient)

Answer (score 3):

Connection has been deprecated. All of the official MongoDB drivers have a new behavior using safe mode on true (No fire-and-forget).

[MongoClient](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient) must be used instead of Connection.

UPDATE:
All new features and changes will be made on MongoClient, not on Connection.