# Class based Wrapper for Python Mongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am looking for a class based wrapper to create mongo connection in python and perform several operations. I started writing some code but thinking  if any existing wrapper available for the similar needs.

```
class MongoDbConn:

    def __init__(self):
        self.settings_mongo = {
            'username': DB_USERID_MONGO,
            'password': DB_PASSWORD_MONGO,
            'host': DB_HOST_MONGO + ":" + DB_PORT_MONGO,
            'database': DB_AUTH_NM_MONGO
        }
        self.mongo_client =\
            MongoClient("mongodb://{username}:{password}@"
                        "{host}/?authSource={database}".format(
                            **self.settings_mongo))

    def execute_operation(self, db_name, collection_name, query,
                          operation):
        assert operation in ["find", "find_one", "distinct"]
        db = self.mongo_client[db_name]
        collection = db[collection_name]
        rs = getattr(collection, operation)(query)
        return rs

    def find_one(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        return self.execute_operation(self, db_name, collection_name, query,
                                      operation="find_one")

    def find(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO

    def delete(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO

    def ensure_index_if_not_exist(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO

    def distinct(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO

    def insert(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO

    def update(self, db_name, collection_name, query):
        TODO
```

So as in above example I am looking for a generic library available of the same nature as above

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what benefit your code provides. It's more complicated and likely a little slower than using PyMongo directly, but other than that I can't see much advantage. Just use PyMongo.

If you're looking for a higher-level Python interface with MongoDB, consider [PyMODM](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which translates between Python objects and MongoDB documents, somewhat like the Django ORM does for SQL rows.

Comment: Thanks @A. Jesse, I am not at all interested in ORM. I want to have genric functions where I should be able to have CRUD operation in mongo. Can you please let me know the reason why the code will be slower, so I can improve it. Do you wanna say I should not be using MongoClient. I took inspiration to use MongoClient from following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959790/pymongo-mongoclient-or-connection

Comment: Just don't create a MongoDbConn directly, create a MongoClient and use it for all your operations. That will require fewer function calls - since if you want to `find` you'll call your MongoClient's `find` function directly instead of calling a function which calls the MongoClient's `find`. It will also be simpler. There is no need to wrap MongoClient in another class that calls MongoClient's functions.

Comment: Sure so I can have mongo client on the global level.Like startup and can use it to write the functions like find, etc. Thanks its helpful